# UIView image background

Tags: ios, uiview, background-image

In my application, I want to set the background image on UIView. In the simulator iOS this code works. And on the iPhone black background. Here's the code:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"appBG.png"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
    UIImage *appbg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:appbg];
}
```

UPDATE: I decided my problem

Comment: Check if the image `[UIImage imageNamed:@"appBG.png"]` is nil when running on device.

Comment: Rendering an image with quartz which is already in the bundle without any dynamic modifications is really a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

its better u will take an ImageView on UIView and set the image to it. Rather than setting the image to UIView.

Comment: Why is that, could you explain? It will be more helpful to others if you can qualify this.

Comment: You can just modify or adjust the ImageView according to iPhone resolutions(iPhone5 and 4s). Also it give you more flexibility and easiness to assign the image very easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
UIImage*    backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"appBG.png"];
CALayer*    aLayer = [CALayer layer];
CGFloat nativeWidth = CGImageGetWidth(backgroundImage.CGImage);
CGFloat nativeHeight = CGImageGetHeight(backgroundImage.CGImage);
CGRect      startFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, nativeWidth, nativeHeight);
aLayer.contents = (id)backgroundImage.CGImage;
aLayer.frame = startFrame;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:aLayer];
[aLayer setNeedsDisplay];
```

Adjust startFrame value according to your requirement.

Comment: I created a new project and it works, but why does not work in this project

Comment: Try to clean your project by all possible ways, 1. Clean build then 2. Close project and remove other contents from contents of xcodeproj file (otherthan pbxproj file) 3. remove your project reference from XCode Organiser>Projects 4. Then open the project again

Comment: And if this answer been helpful to you then can you please upvote and accept the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Replace following line:

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"appBG.png"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
```

With following line:

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"appBG.png"] drawInRect:self.view.frame];
```

May be the issue of frame or bound.